# Remote bibliography files in TeXlipse

Tags: texlipse

I am using TeXlipse and I have several TeX projects. One project, the *MainProject* contains a folder *references* that holds all the bibliography (`.bib`) files that are referenced by the smaller other projects.

In the smaller project, how do I reference the `.bib` file in *MainProject*?

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8, citestyle=numeric, sorting=none,
bibstyle=numeric, maxcitenames=3, mincitenames=1,
maxbibnames=99, minbibnames=99 ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references/books.bib} %books.bib is located in MainProject/src/references/%
```

In the smaller project's properties, I have *MainProject* in the Project References section. That did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to define a library path variable in your latex. All paths are relative to the working directory where latex is called, and this happens outside of eclipse. So having the MainProject in the reference would do no good.

Another solution I can think of is to make a shortcut in your small project that points to the real .bib.

Let us know what worked.